# How can we compute monthly returns, based on daily closing stock prices?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I hacked together this code, shown below, which gets daily returns of stock prices, and parses out the month from the date

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.optimize as sco
import datetime as dt
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
np.random.seed(777)


start = '2018-06-30'
end = '2020-06-30'

tickers = ['AXP','AAPL','BA','CAT','CSCO']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Adj Close']])

df = pd.concat(price_data)
df.dtypes
df.head()
df.shape

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

df = df.reset_index()
df = df.set_index('Date')
table = df.pivot(columns='ticker')
# By specifying col[1] in below list comprehension
# You can select the stock names under multi-level column
table.columns = [col[1] for col in table.columns]
table.head()


table = table.reset_index()
table
```

That gives me this.

[image]

Now, I am trying to get monthly returns for each stock ticker. I Googled some ideas of of how to compute monthly returns from daily closing prices, and I thought it was table.groupby('month'), but that didn't seem to work. How can I convert daily prices to monthly returns?

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to do this.

```
# average monthly returns
df_mth = table.resample('M', on='Date').mean()

# average monthly returns
df_mth = table.set_index('Date').resample('M').mean()
```